# C program to check if a power is equal to another power

Tags: c

I'm writing a piece of code that takes as arguments the base and the exponent of a power, and checks if there is a power with lower base and larger exponent equal to it (max exponent being 100)
I've written this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int equalPower(int base, int esp);

int main(){
    if(equalPower(100,40))
        printf("Unique\n");
    else
        printf("Not unique\n");
    return 0;
}

int equalPower(int base, int esp){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(base); i++){
        for(j = 2; j <= 100; j++){
            if(pow(base,esp) == pow(i,j))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

(I know, in terms of performance it could be improved, but nonetheless it should work this way too.)

As you can see, I'm testing 100^40, which is equal to 10^80, but the program prints out "Unique". I'm clearly missing something. At first I thought that powers like 100^40 were too big to perform tests with, but I tested this separately and it works fine. I don't know why the function doesn't return 0.

Comment: These numbers are too big to be stored in `int`, or any other built-in integral types.

Comment: @YuHao: I know but If I do the test with two big powers, just using the pow function (like: if(pow(100,40) == (pow(10,80)) printf("True") ) it works. I don't understand why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: The result overflows, it still has a result, it's not a surprise that it gives correct result in certain cases. The correct method is to use a big number library, see Evan's answer.

Comment: you could some debug code to see what's the value pow(i, j) is when `i == 10 && j == 80`, and the values of `pow(100, 40)`. make sure they are not `inf` .

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Which architecture are you working on? It would be great if you could provide the compiled binary or the disassembled version (assuming you are working on Linux, `objdump -D binary_file`).

Comment: @MarcoGuerri: I'm working on x64 Windows7. Here is the download link for the binary: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/qe234v51ob3ff4f/prova.rar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not imply using `pow()` since comparing floating point numbers is almost always inaccurate. Instead you have to fall back to Algebra knowledge, and since you're using integer values, I will give you an integer-only solution, which will give you no problem with precisions.

You have to factor the base and see if it is itself a power. Otherwise, you will get not any equality at all. Take this:

```
a ^ b == c ^ d
```

It is a basic algebra fact that, for two numbers to be equal, factorizing such number should give the same result. So, to check if two powers are actually the same, you need:

```
a ^ b == (a1 * a2 * a3 * ... * an) ^ b = c ^ d
```

Values a1, a2, a3, ..., an are prime factors powered to positive integer exponents (0 is not allowed). This would be the same as:

```
a ^ b = a1 ^ b * a2 ^ b * a3 ^ b * ... * an ^ b
```

Let's check if they are the same as `c ^ d`:

```
c ^ d = c1 ^ d * c2 ^ d * c3 ^ d * ... * cn ^ d
```

This, assuming both an and cn are ordered in the same way, it's a theorem that you'll get the exact same representation if both numbers are equal. So you will want to check whether:

```
an ^ b = cn ^ d
```

For each n, and you will quickly discover that cn ^ (something) == an. That means, log(cn, an) will be a (mathematically) integer value. This means that `root(x, an) == cn` (I don't remember the actual name), or `pow(cn, x) == an`, for each an and cn, and a fixed integer x value. However I will not make use of pow() since there are floating point errors.

This means: you only need to check the base, and not the exponent, and check against another base:

```
int check_power(int base, int exponent) {
    if (base == 1) {
        puts("Dude! for 1, the trivial solution is 1^x for every x!");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int newbase=0, newbase<100; newbase++) {
       int newexponent = 0;
       int power = 1;
       while (power < base) {
           power = power * newbase;
           exponent++;
       }
       if (power == base) {
           printf("found! base: %d, exponent: %d", newbase, newexponent * exponent);
           return 1;
       }
    }
    puts("nothing found");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store a number that is equal to 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in an `int`. As Yu Hao mentioned in his comment, this is bigger than any type in C can support. The range for an `int` in C without any modifiers is from -32767 to 32767.
I think the largest number you can get in C is a `long long` type, which ranges from −9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807 (or from 0 to 18446744073709551615 if it is `unsigned`).

You might try the GNU MP Bignum Library (https://gmplib.org/) which has functions to perform applications which involve very large numbers.

Comment: no, typically int's range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 on most modern systems

Comment: The *minimum* range is -32767 to +32767. Specifically, a conforming implementation must have `INT_MIN <= -32767` and `INT_MAX >= 32767`. `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits, and most C compilers don't support any integer types wider than 64 bits. But the standard imposes no upper bound; a conforming compiler *could* support, say, a 1024-bit integer type, which could easily represent 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Answer (score 1):

Note that testing if `a^b == x^y` doesn't require actually doing the exponentiation. Rather you can factor the bases `a` and `x` and multiply the factor counts by their exponent and then compare the lists.

For example `100^40 == 10^80` becomes `[(2, 2), (5, 2)] * 40 == [(2, 1), (5, 1)] * 80` or `[(2, 80), (5, 80)] == [(2, 80), (5, 80)]` which is `true`.

This works because `a^b` contains the factors of `a` repeated `b` times.

This can also be used to enumerate the exponentials that have the same value. Consider that `[(2, x), (5, x)] * y` where `x * y == 80` all denote the same value. The list of base-exponents for `100^40` would be:

```
[(10, 80), 
 (100, 40), 
 (10000, 20), 
 (100000, 16), 
 (100000000, 10), 
 (10000000000, 8), 
 (10000000000000000, 5), 
 (100000000000000000000L, 4), 
 (10000000000000000000000000000000000000000L, 2),
 (100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L, 1)]
```

If you factor the normalized exponent this list is simply what you would get if you compute the unique powerset and remove then from the exponent and multiply the base by them. Consider take `100^40` into `[(2, 2), (5, 2)] * 40` then normalize to `[(2, 1), (5, 1)] * 80` factorize 80 into `[2, 2, 2, 2, 5]` compute the unique powerset `[(), (2,), (2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 2, 5), (2, 2, 2, 5), (2, 2, 5), (2, 5), (5,)]` convert these back to their numbers `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5]`.

Therefore I claim that the function `equalPower` as defined:

```
int equalPower(int base, int esp){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(base); i++){
        for(j = 2; j <= 100; j++){
            if(pow(base,esp) == pow(i,j))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Should be written as:

```
int equalPower(int base, int esp){
    return 0;
}
```

As it is checking a property that is false for all `b^e` when `b` and `e` are integers. There is always at least one other pair `x^y` that equals `b^e`.

Answer (score 0):

In floating point arithmetics generally *two numbers are almost always different* except when one is a copy of the other. So you should avoid direct *exact* comparision like `pow(base,esp) == pow(i,j)` and use some weak comparision instead, like 'are the numbers close enough', equvalent 'is a difference small enough?':

```
if( fabs(pow(base,esp) - pow(i,j)) < some_small_value )
{
    ....
}
```

where small value is something like

```
const double some_small_value = 1e-12;
```

Comment: Your small value, in this case, could be as large as `1.0`, since OP should not have any fractional component anyway (for raising an integer power to an integer power).

Comment: @CiaPan: Thanks for replying. I tried as you said, I've changed the equality test in the function from `if(pow(base,esp) == pow(i,j))` to `if(fabs(pow(base,esp) - pow(i,j)) < small_value)`, but it still prints out "Unique".

Answer (score 0):

You don't have integer overflow here, as `pow` is working only with double. It's clear from the disassembled code below, which shows the
*second call* to `pow(i,j)` and the comparison between the results

```
401726:       db 45 f0                fildl  -0x10(%ebp)
401729:       db 45 f4                fildl  -0xc(%ebp)
40172c:       d9 c9                   fxch   %st(1)
40172e:       dd 5c 24 08             fstpl  0x8(%esp)
401732:       dd 1c 24                fstpl  (%esp)
401735:       e8 f6 14 00 00          call   402c30 <_pow>
40173a:       dd 45 e0                fldl   -0x20(%ebp)
40173d:       df e9                   fucomip %st(1),%st
40173f:       7a 10                   jp     401751 <_equalPower+0x5a>
401741:       dd 45 e0                fldl   -0x20(%ebp)
401744:       df e9                   fucomip %st(1),%st
401746:       dd d8                   fstp   %st(0)
401748:       75 09                   jne    401753 <_equalPower+0x5c>
40174a:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
40174f:       eb 31                   jmp    401782 <_equalPower+0x8b>
```

In order:

- `0x401726`: load a 32 bits integer (i or j) in a floating point register.
- `0x401729`: same as above.
- `0x40172e`: store the 64 bits floating point representation of the integer variable on the stack.
- `0x401732`: same as above.
- `0x401735`: call to pow
- `0x40173a`: load the result of the first `pow` in a floating point register. The second result is already in another FP register.
- `0x40173d`: compare the two 64 bits values in the floating point registers.

So, no integers involved.

With a **64bit IEEE754 float**, you can represent integers even bigger than `10^80`. However, you won't be able to represent them precisely:
you can only use the closest integer value representable. This requires
some knowledge of the IEEE754 format, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) Wikipedia page is
very clear.

Considering only positive integers (add sign for negative ones), with
a 52 bits mantissa, you can represent exactly integer numbers in the
interval `[1,2^53[`. For bigger values, you need to use exponents `> 2^52`. The idea is the following:

- `[2^53,2^54[`: you need to multiply your mantissa by `2*2^52`, one shift left with respect to the maximum integer number. You can represent only even numbers.
- `[2^54,2^55[`: you need to multiply your mantissa by `4*2^52`. Only multiples of 4 are representable.

And so on and so forth. The result of `pow(10,80)` on my machine is
`1[...some zeros...]2660986470836727653740[...]` (82 digits). That's the closest
value with numbers of that magnitude. What I believe happens here is
that your two calls to `pow` are leading to different results because at some point, the two `pow` calculations start to drift away from the exact value. You will eventually compare two different numbers.

**Why is pow(100,40) == pow(10,80) working?**

The compiler is optimizing the code. It recognizes that your
comparison is always true, and it basically optimizes
it out. Example on my machine (gcc 4.7.2):

```
int main(){
    if(pow(100,40) == pow(10,80))
        printf("Equal!\n");
[...]
```

"Equal" is printed on stdout. But...

```
00000000004006d0 <main>:
  4006d0:       55                      push   %rbp
  4006d1:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4006d4:       bf 80 08 40 00          mov    $0x400880,%edi
  4006d9:       e8 a2 fe ff ff          callq  400580 <puts@plt>
```

You can clearly see that there's no call to `pow`, the compiler
figures out that it's useless and calls `puts` straight away. I can't
try it out on Visual Studio, but I believe the situation is identical.

Answer (score 0):

`if(pow(base,esp) == pow(i,j))`

That line can not be relied upon to evaluate as true, even if it's true.

`pow()` returns a floating point number, which is prone to accuracy issues.  It is entirely possible (and probable) that the two values, while close to each other, are not exactly the same due to hardware limitations.

`double` and `float` are just estimates.  There are few (if any) cases where it makes sense to perform equality operations with them.